# emacs reftex hangs up while Scanning bibliography database

Tags: reftex-mode

I've a strange reftex-issue. When i insert a cite from a bib-file, emacs hangs up. I've tried this on two different machines: Windows 7 and on Mac OS X. (GNU Emacs 24.5.1)

Insert a cite: Open emacs, the bibliography file is loaded with:

```
(setq reftex-default-bibliography
    '("/Users/user/CloudStation/repositories_d/pandoc-templates/examples/socbib-pandoc.bib"))
```

(the bib file exists and is accessible)

Open a `.tex` file and press `C-c [` `^M` and enter `b*`.

Now emacs shows the message:

> Scanning bibliography database socbib-pandoc.bib

and HANGS UP. Why?

Comment: You asked the same question on the AUCTeX list. If you ask it on multiple channels, please cite the other ones, too. And when you get a correct answer, please update the other locations with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression `b*` matches the empty string, thus the search for matching entries in the bib file won't make any progress.

I have fixed that in emacs' master branch so it will be in 25.1. With that, you get an error when you try searching for bib entries with a regular expression which matches the empty string.